# settings in jboss-log4j.xml not taking effect

Tags: log4j, jboss5.x

I have a war file that I deployed to `JBOSS_HOME/server/default/deploy`.

I add the following to the `JBOSS_HOME/server/default/conf/jboss-log4j.xml`

```
 <appender name="FILE" class="org.jboss.logging.appender.DailyRollingFileAppender">
            <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
            <param name="File" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/server.log"/>
            <param name="Append" value="false"/>
            <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>

            <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>

            <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] %m%n"/>
            </layout>
    </appender>
```

I restarted the server,

But the logs are not writing under `Server.log`,

Logs are generating under `boot.log` (including my war deployment logs also) in the path `JBOSS_HOME/server/default/logs/`.

(Im running Jboss with JDK7 on linux.)

Comment: This is more a log4j issue, you should add the corresponding tag.

Answer (score 0):

See root section, add `<appender-ref ref="FILE"/>`:

```
    <!-- ======================= -->
   <!-- Setup the Root category -->
   <!-- ======================= -->

   <root>
      <!-- 
         Set the root logger priority via a system property. Note this is parsed by log4j,
         so the full JBoss system property format is not supported; e.g.
         setting a default via ${jboss.server.log.threshold:WARN} will not work.         
       -->
      <priority value="${jboss.server.log.threshold}"/>
      <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
      <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
   </root>
```

Answer (score 0):

Defining an appender is not enough in itself. You need to associate that appender with one or more loggers in the logger hierarchy. If you look at the other parts of the file, you'll see loggers defined which use the `<appender-ref>` element. This sends output from that logger to that appender.

If all you want to do is to send *all* logging to your new appender, then add `<appender-ref>` to the `<root>` element, which defines the root logger, e.g.

```
<root>
  <!-- existing config in <root> -->
  <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>   <!-- reference to my new appender -->
</root>
```

See this [tutorial at JavaLobby](http://java.dzone.com/articles/configuring-logging-jboss) for more details.